# logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1568,10] and labels shape [32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

i'm a deep learning enthusiasts, and i want finetune the keras.application deep model to train a new model, but something wrong. And the code is :

```
import keras.applications.resnet_v2
from keras.applications.resnet_v2 import ResNet50V2
from keras.applications.resnet_v2 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from keras.models import Model
import os
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()#train_szie :(60000, 28, 28)
print(x_train.shape)#(60000, 28, 28)
print(y_train.shape)#(60000,)
x_train = [cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(img,(28,28)),cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) for img in x_train]  
x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
x_test = [cv2.cvtColor(cv2.resize(img,(28,28)),cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) for img in x_test] 
x_test = np.asarray(x_test)
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

base_model = ResNet50V2( weights='imagenet', include_top = False)
x = base_model.get_layer("conv2_block1_preact_bn").output
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

when i run it, the code is error,named

```
"res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1568,10] and labels shape [32]
         [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4157]"
```

but when i write the code, is now running fine.

```
x = base_model.output
```

I don't know why,i need your help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few changes required in your code and has multiple issues.

You're missing a Flatten layer in the middle. Because of that, when computing loss (with a 1D vector of labels), `tensorflow` squash all of the dimensions except the last together giving [7 x 7 x32 = 1568, 200] sized set of logits. Here 7x7 is the output width and height for a 28x28 sized input by your last conv layer. 32 is default batch size when using `model.fit()`. This is not compatible with the labels which would simply be a 32 item 1d vector in one iteration.

```
base_model = ResNet50V2(weights='imagenet', include_top = False)

# Input the way you've defined has undefined width and heigh
# dimension. This is an important requirement for the Flatten layer downstream
input = Input(shape=(28,28,3))
x = input

# Getting only the layers we care about
for layer in base_model.layers:

  x = layer(x)

  if layer.name == "conv2_block1_preact_bn":
    break

# Before feeding data into the dense layer, you need to flatten
x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x) 
predictions = Dense(200, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

One concern I have is that `mnist` has 10 classes, so your last layer should only need 10 not 200